# Individual Document Library Permission - SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions

I would like to know if it's possible give individual file permissions in a document library. ie If I have two documents in my library and two members. I would like User A to be able to edit one document, but have read only access to the next etc. Appreciate any help on this. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Try the below steps to give individual file permissions

1.Choose the file and click Managed Access in the detail panel.

[image]

2.Grant access to the user, you could chosse "Can edit" or "Can view"

[image]